# Maximum safe dosage of zinc for 4-6 weeks

Tags: supplement, dosage, deficiency, zinc, wilsons-disease

After refractive surgery, the doctor suggested taking 1000mg of vitamin C daily to help minimize scarring.  When I went to pick up the vitamins, I also noticed that there was a supplement claiming to be designed to support eye health that also included vitamin C.  Specifically, it has:

- 250mg vitamin C
- 200 IU vitamin E
- 40mg zinc (as 50mg zinc oxide)
- 1mg copper

...per tablet.  The recommended dosage is 1 tablet/day, and I'd have to take 4 times that amount to get 1000mg of vitamin C/day.

From what I can determine 800 IU of vitamin E and 4 mg copper are within safe/tolerable limits, however 160mg of elemental zinc is quite high.  There are only a few conditions I can find where dosages around that level are recommended for therapeutic purposes:

- Acne (for up to 8 weeks)
- Wilson's disease (ongoing)
- Macular degeneration (ongoing)

So my question is, what's the safe maximum dosage of zinc over a course of 4-6 weeks?  From what I can find, it seems like the biggest risk is that high dosages of zinc lead to copper deficiency (hence why it's used to as a treatment for Wilson's disease).  Does it therefore follow that 160mg/day should be okay as long as it's supplemented with some extra copper and not continued on a long-term basis?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, too much zinc could be harmfull but in your case you are at the upper limit.

Zinc supplements should **not exceed 40mg** per day for adults.
You find all details here: https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/Zinc-Consumer/#h8

Hope this helps.